# Branch cut of $\sqrt{z^2 -1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, branch-cuts

I am trying to find out the maximum domain on $\mathbb{C}$, where the function $f=\sqrt{z^2 -1}$, $z\in \mathbb{C}$ becomes holomorphic.

I know that $\sqrt{z^2-1} = e^{\frac{1}{2}(log\left | z^2-1 \right | + iArg(z^2-1) +2\pi k)}$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

and that there are two discontinuous solutions given, but how do I manipulate the complex plane so that those solutions become continuous? An intuive as well as an mathematical explanation would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The two singularities are at $z=1$ and $z=-1$.  For your branch cut, take any curve connecting those two points.

Comment: And to add to the comment by @GEdgar, you may connect the branch points at the point at infinity.  For example, you may cut the plane from $z=-1$ to $z=-\infty$ with a ray along the negative real axis and from $z=1$ to $z=\infty$ with a ray along the positive real axis.

Comment: ![Visualize](https://i.imgur.com/IvVLInW.png)